# Decimal separator and axis label centering with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, comma-separated-list

The following code creates a `figure` with Tikz without the use of `pfgplots` (that I want to avoid here):

```
% compilation: pdflatex --jobname=Runge-f1 Runge.tex
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfrealjobname{Runge}

\begin{filecontents}{B6.dat}
-1  0
0   5
1   0
\end{filecontents}
\definecolor{rouge}{RGB}{233,55,77}

\def\xmin{-1.1}\def\xmax{1.1}\def\ymin{-.6}\def\ymax{5.6}

\begin{document}
\beginpgfgraphicnamed{Runge-f1}%
\footnotesize
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1.4,x=4cm,y=1cm]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% background
\fill[rouge!10] (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
%%%% grid and labels
\begin{scope}
\clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
\foreach \x in {-1,-0.75,...,1} \draw[rouge!35] (\x,\ymin) -- (\x,\ymax);
\foreach \x in {-1,-0.75,...,1} \node[fill=rouge!10,inner sep=2pt,anchor=south,font=\tiny\color{rouge}] at (\x,-.5){$\mathsf\x$}; %%%%%% loop 1
\end{scope}
%%%% curve
\draw plot file{B6.dat};
%%%% external frame
\draw[line width=.6pt,rouge!50] (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}
\endpgfgraphicnamed%
\end{document}
```

- how is it possible to have a comma as the decimal separator in loop 1?
- in loop 1, would it be possible to center the `$\x$` labels with respect to the grid by ignoring the negative sign `-` when present?

[image]

Comment: I unfortunately don't understand the second question _in loop 1, would it be possible to place the $\x$ label by ignoring the negative sign '-' when present?_ could you maybe rephrase it?

Comment: On the horizontal axis, labels -1, -0.75, -0.5 and -0.25 should be centered with respect to the grid by ignoring the - sign.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can work with `siunitx`. Therefore I defined a command:

```
\usepackage{siunitx}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{ \parsenumber } { m }
{
 \num[ output-decimal-marker = { , }]{\fp_eval:n { abs ( #1 ) }}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Your loop looks like:

```
\foreach \x in {-1,-0.75,...,1} \node[fill=rouge!10,inner sep=2pt,anchor=south,font=\tiny\color{rouge}] at (\x,-.5){ \parsenumber{\x} }; %%%%%% loop 1
```

---

It seems the minus symbol should be displayed without taking any space. Then, you can use:

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{ \parsenumber } { m }
{
 \num[ output-decimal-marker = { , },bracket-negative-numbers,close-bracket={},open-bracket={\llap{$-$}}]{#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
```

Result:

> [image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks promising. About question 2, I do not want to remove the minus sign in the output, I just want to ignore it for the positioning.

Comment: @pluton: Fixed it. (I hope). Is this what you wanted.

Comment: @JosephWright: Sorry for the misusing of your package ;-)

Comment: Nice. How can we keep the `\mathsf` font?

Comment: @pluton: You can use `{$\mathsf{\parsenumber{\x}}$};` whereby you need the following options inside `num`: `\num[detect-family = true, detect-inline-family = math,output-decimal-marker = { , },bracket-negative-numbers,close-bracket={},open-bracket={\llap{$\mathsf-$}}]{#1}`

Comment: Add `text depth=+0pt` (or any other fixed value, say `\depthof{$,$}`) to the node’s option to vertically align the nodes or use the `.base` anchor to place the nodes (see my answer).

Answer (score 7):

You can also parse your number with PGF.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{B6.dat}
-1  0
0   5
1   0
\end{filecontents}
\definecolor{rouge}{RGB}{233,55,77}

\def\xmin{-1.1}\def\xmax{1.1}\def\ymin{-.6}\def\ymax{5.6}

\begin{document}

\footnotesize
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1.4,x=4cm,y=1cm]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% background
\fill[rouge!10] (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
%%%% grid and labels
\begin{scope}
\clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
\foreach \x in {-1,-0.75,...,1}{ \draw[rouge!35] (\x,\ymin) -- (\x,\ymax);}
\foreach \x in {-1,-0.75,...,1}{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myshift}{(\x < 0? -0.4 : 0)}
\node[fill=rouge!10,
      inner sep=2pt,
      anchor=base,
      font=\tiny\color{rouge},
      xshift=\myshift em
      ]  at (\x,-.5) {$\mathsf{\pgfmathprintnumber[use comma]{\x}}$}; %%%%%% loop 1
}
\end{scope}
%%%% curve
\draw plot file{B6.dat};
%%%% external frame
\draw[line width=.6pt,rouge!50] (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I've just guessed the width of a minus but you can also measure it.

[image]

Comment: yes, the `xshift` idea is smart. With, Qrrbrbirlbel's `\x\ifdim\x pt<0pt\hphantom{-}\fi` test, that should be fine!

Answer (score 6):

A slightly different approach then percusse’s:

We use PGF math’s `\pgfmathprintnumber` macro with

- the option `use comma` and
- the option `zero-width sign` which uses `mathtools`’ `\mathllap` macro that is `\robustify`-ed by `etoolbox`. You can also use  `\llap` instead (see comment in code).

Two special macros from the `pgfmathprintnumber` needs to adjusted for this. (I have ignored the `show pos` option here that forces a plus sign.)

A rather unorthodox but safe approach would be to use `\x\ifdim\x pt<0pt\hphantom{-}\fi`, i.e. checking if `\x` is less then `0` (works only if `\x` is already an evaluated, expandable value) and add a hidden `-` after the number, thus centering the sign-less part of the number.

Both solutions have the disadvantage that the node’s border do not correlate to the actual text. (But if you use neither `draw` nor the border on the west and the right side, this shouldn’t be a problem.)

I also included the node from the second loop in the first loop, so that one doesn’t have to `fill` the node, this makes the drawing independent from the background (the just may be a line or a shading going on). This is usually also doable with the `markings` decoration and the `mark connection node` options, though that has failed me today.

I also included `text depth=+0pt` in the node options with sets the depth of the node text box to zero hiding the depth of the `,` and of `-` which would result in slightly different vertical alignment of the nodes because we have three different types of input:

- (zero-)positive integer (neither `,` nor `-`)
- negative integer (only `-`)
- positive and negative floats (depth of `,` is greater than the depth of `-`).

Another solution would be to use the `base` anchor to place the nodes instead of the (default) `center` one.

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\begin{filecontents}{B6.dat}
-1  0
0   5
1   0
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage{etoolbox,mathtools}
\robustify\mathllap
\makeatletter
\newif\ifpgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@sign
\def\pgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@#1{\mathllap{#1}}% or \llap{$#1$} without mathtools/etoolbox
\pgfqkeys{/pgf/number format}{zero-width sign/.is if=pgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@sign,zero-width sign/.default=true}
\def\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@impl@noperiod@printsign#1{%
    \def\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb{#1}%
    \edef\pgf@tempa{\ifpgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@sign\pgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@{#1}\else#1\fi}%
    \ifx\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb\pgfmathfloatparsenumber@tok@MINUS
        \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\pgfmathresult\pgf@tempa}%
        \let\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb=\pgfutil@empty
    \else
        \ifx\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb\pgfmathfloatparsenumber@tok@PLUS
            \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\def\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{\expandafter\pgfmathresult\pgf@tempa}%
            \let\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb=\pgfutil@empty
        \else
            \ifpgfmathprintnumber@showpositive
                \expandafter\def\expandafter\pgfmathresult\expandafter{\pgfmathresult +}%
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    \ifnum\c@pgf@counta>0
        \def\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@impl@noperiod@NEXT{%
            \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@impl@noperiod@printtrailingdigits\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb
        }%
    \else
        \def\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@impl@noperiod@NEXT{%
            \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@impl@noperiod@counteverythird\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb
        }%
    \fi
    \pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@impl@noperiod@NEXT
}
\def\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@impl@noperiod@printall#1{%
    \def\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb{#1}%
    \let\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPc=\pgfutil@empty
    \ifx\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb\pgfmathfloatparsenumber@tok@MINUS
        \ifpgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@sign
            \let\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPc\pgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@
        \fi
    \else
        \ifx\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPb\pgfmathfloatparsenumber@tok@PLUS
            \ifpgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@sign
                \let\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPc\pgfmathprintnumber@zerowidth@
            \fi
        \else
            \ifpgfmathprintnumber@showpositive
                \def\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPc{+}%
            \fi
        \fi
    \fi
    \expandafter\pgfmathprintnumber@fixed@styleDEFAULT@impl@noperiod@printall@\pgfmathfloat@loc@TMPc#1%
}
\makeatother

\definecolor{rouge}{RGB}{233,55,77}
\def\xmin{-1.1}\def\xmax{1.1}\def\ymin{-.6}\def\ymax{5.6}
\begin{document}
\footnotesize
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex,scale=1.4,x=4cm,y=1cm]
%%%% background
\fill[rouge!10] (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
%%%% grid and labels
\begin{scope}
\clip (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
\foreach \x in {-1,-0.75,...,1}
  \path[rouge!35] 
    node[inner sep=2pt,anchor=south,font=\tiny\everymath{\color{rouge}\mathsf},text depth=+0pt] at (\x,-.5) {\pgfmathprintnumber[zero-width sign,use comma]{\x}}
      edge (\x,\ymin)
      edge (\x,\ymax);
\end{scope}
%%%% curve
\draw plot file{B6.dat};
%%%% external frame
\draw[line width=.6pt,rouge!50] (\xmin,\ymin) rectangle (\xmax,\ymax);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Very involved! I'm no sure how you can know all this!??

Answer (score 2):

To solve the second part of your question:
I would split up the second loop into two loops. In the first loop covering the negative values you can use a yshift by the 3pt (which is the amount of space the minus singt takes.

```
\foreach \x in {-1,-0.75,...,-0.25} \node[fill=rouge!10,inner  
   sep=2pt,anchor=south,font=\tiny\color{rouge}, xshift = -3pt] at (\x,-.5){$\mathsf\x$}; 
\foreach \x in {0,0.25,...,1} \node[fill=rouge!10,inner 
   sep=2pt,anchor=south,font=\tiny\color{rouge}] at (\x,-.5){$\mathsf\x$};
```